# Identity Server 4: logout from external provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have an MVC client app (APP1) protected by Identity Server. I use a backchannel mechanism to log out of clients as soon as user logs out of idsrv. Pretty similar to this one: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/samples/Clients/src/MvcHybridBackChannel/Startup.cs

Now the thing is: I need to add a support for external provider, Azure AD. And in turn it also should support automatic log out: when a user logs out of Azure AD, he should be logged out of idsrv and from the client apps.

My first idea was to implement the same approach: Azure App registration supports the ability to call client's endpoint upon log out. But I'm struggling with the part when I need to set up custom CookieAuthenticationEvents. The code which I have in a client app APP1:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
  options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
  options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
}).AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
{
  options.EventsType = typeof(CookieEventHandler);
}
```

But the same code doesn't work in idsrv. But this I mean that my cookie is not being validated by my custom CookieEventHandler. Can anyone point me in a right direction?

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to let Azure AD call the **Logout** method on the **AccountController** to sign out the user. (or if you make your own "logout" endpoint).

The logout method is protected by a ValidateAntiForgeryToken, so you might need to get around that by creating your "own" logout endpoint.

But basically what you need to do on a high level is to let AzureAD trigger a call to the
HttpContext.SignOutAsync(); method.